# bind variables in get_query() - RMD files

Tags: sql, r, data-binding

I've been trying to solve the following problem.
I'm trying to create an RMD template. I'm pulling the data using the get_query() method, and in the query, i'm using bind variables with ilike operator in the following way: `ilike '%' || :bindvalue || '%'`  .

When I try to knit (to run the query) it pops the following problem: parse error, syntax error 'US', syntax error ')' .

But when I delete the ilike with the bind it runs perfectly.
Is it possible to bind variables with ilike operator on RMD? maybe someone knows any workaround it? or maybe it is a problem with glue parameter?

my query:

```
geo <- 'US'
geo_url <- '.com'

geo_general_info <- get_query("SELECT
MERCHANT_NAME, industry, business_plan ,went_live_at, count(order_id) as order_cnt ,sum(order_value) as  orders_tot_value
FROM orders o left join merchnats m using(MERCHANT_ID)
where went_live_at is not null
AND ((m.MERCHANT_NAME ilike '%' || :geo || '%') or (m.HQ ilike '%' || :bindvalue || '%' )
         or (m.URL ilike  '%' ||:geo_url || '' ))
group by 1
order by 5 desc;", glue_parameters = list(geo = geo, geo_url = geo_url))

Thanks!
```

Comment: The question cannot possibly be related to mysql as mysql does not support the `ilike` operator.

Comment: It may be from `adsDataHubR`, not sure. Kaufman41, please be specific about non-base packages.

Comment: Is `merhcnats` real or should it be `merchants`?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, just a typo here (I've changed some of tables and columns names to be more readable)

Comment: @r2evans What do you mean? I'm using `tidyverse,  plotly, glue, kableExtra`. I use other packages but they aren't related (the connection to the db is working fine).

Comment: In which package is `get_query`? It's a database query but is not `DBI`. So "what do I mean"? You have code in your question that is neither base R nor is it obvious (not a very-common/popular package). I thought you would be able to confirm it correct my other comment where I made a guess.

Comment: The error suggests you need to add quotes, perhaps `"select ... ilike '%' || ':geo' ..."`.

Comment: @r2evans You are correct, I'm using my company package. Since the db query is working both in R and in SQL i don't think the problem is in the package or the query itself. I also know that this package can work with bind variables. I think my problem is with the bind or the glue parameters. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I understand, and have a similar company-only (internal) package for SQL work. Is there a way you can look at the query that is actually being sent?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, it is. When I write a similar query without the `ilike` it works perfectly so I basically think that this is the problem (the bind variable in `ilike` operator)

Comment: As a side point, if you have any influence over the company package: I understand the use of `glue_sql` (or similar use of `glue`) and its use to preempt inadvertent sql-injection or just query-corruption, an alternative (that is better in some senses) is to use bound-parameters. You say you're binding here, but the naming convention of `glue_parameters` suggests that `get_query` will add the strings into the query instead of using [real parameter binding](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries). The latter is theoretically a little better/faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It.
The problem was the bind variable with '_' sign.
After petrifying the previous code i posted, the solution is:

```
(m.MERCHANT_NAME ilike :geo ) or (m.HQ ilike :geo )
         or (m.URL ilike :geourl ))
```

and the parameters are (for example): `geo = "%geoname%", geourl = "%value"`